# How do I rename an XML element with the value of its first attribute using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, rename, element

I am new to XSLT and have XML structures that look like this:

```
  <Loop LoopId="1000A" Name="SUBMITTER NAME">
  .... a bunch of sub-elements, etc. 
  </Loop>
```

I am trying to write an XSLT that will convert them all to this: 
(concatenate the value of the LoopId attribute to its parent element name)

```
  <Loop1000A LoopId="1000A" Name="SUBMITTER NAME">
  .... a bunch of sub-elements, etc. 
  </Loop1000A>
```

I have a style sheet that gets me almost all of the way there, but it is getting rid of the attribute LoopId and I don't know why - the style sheet below produces this result:

```
  <Loop1000A Name="SUBMITTER NAME">
  .... a bunch of sub-elements, etc. 
  </Loop1000A>
```

Is there a way to modify it so I keep the LoopId attribute?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@LoopId"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[@LoopId]">
     <xsl:variable name="vRep" select="concat('Loop',@LoopId)"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$vRep}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Thanks

Comment: Sorry -  editing error - in the above example "@Id" should actually be "@LoopId"

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? It produces a very difficult to process XML.

Comment: Please don't change your question to a completely different one after the original question has already been answered!

Comment: sorry about @michael.hor257k that  was my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the template `<xsl:template match="@LoopId"/>` as that way you remove the `LoopId` attribute.

Comment: Thanks so much - that's exactly what I want. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<xsl:element name="concat('Loop', @LoopId)">
```

to:

```
<xsl:element name="{concat('Loop', @LoopId)}">
```

See:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#attribute-value-templates

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful . I knew it was going to be something silly.